# Draw rounded corners by erasing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Let's say there is a rectangle of BitmapData called **bmd** of *width* **w** and *height* **h**

We now want to turn it into a rounded rectangle with corners of *ellipseSize* **e**, roughly equivalent to if we had drawn a rectangle via:

```
var shape:Shape;
shape.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,w,h,e);
```

How would you paint out the corners so that the resulting BitmapData (either **bmd** itself or a new copy) appears to have rounded corners, looking like those created by the Shape.graphics.drawRoundRect() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to `mask` your `Bitmap` with your rounded rectangle, and then to use the `draw` method.